# How to reverse x XOR (x >>> 1) XOR (x >>> 2)

Tags: hash

### **Short version:**

What is the inversion of $f(x) = x \oplus (x \lll 1) \oplus (x \lll 5)$ when the last 4 bits of $x$ are known?

### **Long version:**

Hi,

a friend a mine and I are giving each other crypto challenges to break. This time, he gave me a "one-way" function which is defined as followed:

$R(x)= x \oplus (x \lll 1) \oplus (x \lll (x\ AND\ 15)) \oplus ((x\ AND\ 15) \lll 1)$

Or if you define $i = x\ AND\ 15$:

$R(x) = x \oplus (x \lll 1) \oplus (x \lll i) \oplus (i \lll 1)$

Given you can bruteforce $i$ (since it is ranged from 0 to 15), there are a few things you can do:

For $i = 0$: $R(x)$ can be reduced to $R(x)=x \oplus (x \lll 1) \oplus x \oplus (i \lll 1)=(x \lll 1) \oplus (i \lll 1)$ which can easily be reversed.

The same applies to $i = 1$ which allowes you to reduce $R(x)$ to $x \oplus (i \lll 1)$.

However, things get more complicated for $i \ge 2$ since the xor's no longer negate themselves, but since you "know" the last 4 bits of $x$, you can try to reverse the function by building upon $i$:

Given that $x_{28-31} = i_{0-3}$ and $0 \le i \le 3$

$x_{27} = x_{27} \oplus x_{28} \oplus x_{27 + i}$

$x_{26} = x_{26} \oplus x_{27} \oplus x_{26 + i}$

...

$x_{n} = x_{n} \oplus x_{n + 1} \oplus x_{n + i}$

($x_n$ or $i_n$ are the $n$th bit of $x$ / $i$)

However, i really have no clue when it comes to $i \gt 3$ since you cant access the plain bits anymore.

// EDIT: The $f(x)=x\oplus (x \lll 1)$ can easily be broken by defining that $x_0=0$ and then calculating the rest using $x_{n}=x_{n-1} \oplus x_{n}$ but I wasn't really able to expand this to the problem above.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to invert $f(x) = x \oplus (x \lll 1) \oplus (x \lll 5)$ (where all quantities are 32-bit), we do not need the low-order bits of $x$; given $f(x)$ we can find $x$.

Let's first solve $f(x)=1$ for $x$. We must have (where $x_i$ is bit $i$ of $x$, with $i=0$ for the low-order bit)
$$\begin{align}x_{0}\oplus x_{31}\oplus x_{27}&=1\\x_{i}\oplus x_{(i+31\bmod32)}\oplus x_{(i+27\bmod32)}&=0\;\text{ for }1\le i<32\end{align}$$

This is a system of 32 linear equations with 32 unknowns, and the tried and tested method of Gaussian elimination yields
$x_0=1$, $x_1=1$, $x_2=1$, $x_3=0$, $x_4=1$, $x_5=0$, $\dots$, $x_{27}=1$, $x_{28}=0$, $x_{29}=0$, $x_{30}=1$, $x_{31}=1$, which we can combine into $x=\mathtt{0xCAF84657}$ which indeed is such that $f(x)=1$ (see second part for alternative methods, based on polynomial arithmetic or brute force).

Given the rotation-invariant structure of $f$, it follows that for $0\le i<32$, the solution of $f(x)=(1\lll i)$ is $x=(\mathtt{0xCAF84657}\lll i)=k_i$.

And because $f$ is linear, we can solve $f(x)=y$ by combining with $\oplus$ those $k_i$ such that bit $i$ of $y$ is set; the combination being the desired $x$.

Or, for a more direct expression, we can write $x=y\oplus(y\lll1)\oplus(y\lll2)\oplus\dots\oplus(y\lll27)\oplus(y\lll30)\oplus(y\lll31)$ where the rotations $i$ in the terms are those such that bit $i$ is set in $k_0=\mathtt{0xCAF84657}$ (argument: this is such that $y=1$ yield $x=k_0$, and the rest follows by linearity and rotation invariance).

---

The Boolean matrix defining the system of equations is [circulant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circulant_matrix); that allows finding $k_0$ by finding the inverse of the Boolean polynomial $1+z+z^5$ modulo $1+z^{32}$ using the Extended Euclidean algorithm for polynomials; see [related answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2315921/35016).

More directly, with the indexes of the bits set in $x$ [resp. $y$ ] the coefficients of the Boolean polynomial $X(z)$ [resp. $Y(z)$ ], we have
$$y=f(x)\iff Y(z)=F(z)\,X(z)\bmod(1+z^{32})\;\text{ with }F(z)=1+z+z^5$$
thus inverting $F$ modulo $1+z^{32}$ (if possible) gives us $G$ which is to $f^{-1}$ what $F$ is to $f$.

In Mathematica, the Extended Euclidean algorithm for Boolean polynomials $1+z+z^5$ and $1+z^{32}$ is invoked as
`{g,{u,v}} = PolynomialExtendedGCD[1+z+z^5, 1+z^32, z, Modulus->2]`
giving the following result, where `g` of 1 at the beginning confirms that $f$ is invertible, and the bits sets in $k_0$ [and the rotation counts in the expression for $f^{-1}(y)$ ] are given by the coefficients of `u`, which I isolated on the second line:
`{1,{`
`1+z+z^2+z^4+z^6+z^9+z^10+z^14+z^19+z^20+z^21+z^22+z^23+z^25+z^27+z^30+z^31`
`,z^3+z^4}}`

For my initial answer, I actually neither did this, nor solve the linear system. If the problem was for more than 32-bit variables, I'd do that; but here I used brute force and wrote this C code which output `0xCAF84657` in about 5 seconds:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main(void) {
    uint32_t x=0;
    do
        if ((x^((x<<1)^(x>>31))^((x<<5)^(x>>27)))==1)
            printf("0x%08lX\n",(unsigned long)x);
    while(++x);
    return 0;
    }
```